# Como desagrupar una matriz

Tags: mongodb

Tengo el siguiente documento en mongoDB y quiero quitar la matriz para que aparezca como esta abajo.
**Documento original**

```
 {
    "_id" : "2022052100000081849",
    "nombre": "JuanFran",
    "edad" : "25"   
    "direccion" : [ 
        {
            "calle" : "gran via",
            "numero" : "14",
            "codigo postal" : "28001"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Documento resultado**

```
{
    "_id" : "2022052100000081849",
    "nombre" : "JuanFran",
    "edad" : "25", 
    "calle" : "gran via",
    "numero" : "14",
    "codigo postal" : "28001"
}
```

A lo maximo que he llegado ha sido a hacer esto db.getCollection('clientes').distinct("direccion") pero pierdo los _id y no sé como meter el resultado en otra collecion nueva. He probado con $out: 'NUEVOCLIENTES' = db.getCollection('clientes').distinct("direccion") y da error.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado? La documentación explica como hacer esto de forma muy clara, ¿lo has buscado?

Comment: A lo maximo que he llegado ha sido a hacer esto  db.getCollection('clientes').distinct("direccion") pero pierdo los _id y no sé como meter el resultado en otra collecion nueva. He probado con $out: 'NUEVOCLIENTES' =db.getCollection('clientes').distinct("direccion") y da error

Comment: Añade eso a tu pregunta, haciendo clic en [edit].